# Confusion about Printing string arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This is probably a beginner question but it has been confusing me.  I understand that in c an array is itself a pointer to the first element of the array.  So consider the following example

```
char *words[LENGTH];
words[0] = "zero";
words[1] = "one";
words[2] = "two";
printf("%s\n",*words);
```

What ends up printing is `zero`.  However, my understanding is that `words` is a pointer to the first element of the `words` array which is a char pointer => `words` is a pointer to a pointer to a char.  Therefore `*words` would be a pointer to char.  Therefore I would expect a memory address to be printed here and not an actual string.  What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: You're de-referencing it, as it's already a pointer.  Removing the `*` when printing should print its memory address.

Comment: Hint: Try changing `%s` to `%c` in the `printf` function.

Comment: "in c an array is itself a pointer to the first element of the array" --> No.  An array is not a pointer.  In many situations,bit not all, though, an array is converted to the address of the first element,

Comment: `words` is an array, each of its `LENGTH` elements is (hopefully, some time after a proper assignment) a pointer. The expression `*words` is the same as `words[0]` and is a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close in fact you are right, c-string are a **pointer** that contain the **address** of the first char of the string. The c-string is not the bytes but the address. And printf flag `%s` expect the address of these bytes. So you indeed give an address to `printf()` but you ask to `printf()` to show the value of the c-string. So "zero". Your only error is that you didn't read the manual of [`printf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

If you want the address try:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)*words);
```

Comment: interesting.  printf() is more complex than I originally thought :)

Comment: "c-string is not the bytes but the address" differs from the C specification  "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."  In C, _strings_ are _not_ pointers.

Comment: @chux I think is easier to understand like that. To read and understand the C standard, in my opinion you need 5 years of experience in C :p. Sometime "lie" is a good way to explain.

Comment: @Stargateur: "lying" is ***never*** a good way to explain something, *especially* in C.  It's this kind of misinformation that results in code that's insecure, incorrect, and dangerous.  This is why crap like Heartbleed happens, because people are being *lied to* about how the language works.  Explain it **correctly** or don't bother explaining it at all.

Comment: @JohnBode Well, I disagree, first this is not my fault if openssl programmer do mistake. Secondly, I don't think that what I say can lead to bugs. Third, I think that this little lie permit to better understand the pointer and so to make less mistake. I think the primary reason to Heartbleed is stupidity.

Comment: @Stargateur: how does misinformation lead to *better understanding* of anything?  Programmers who are misinformed about a language are *more likely* to make mistakes, not less.  Herb Schildt poisoned the minds of an entire generation of C programmers with similar misinformation, and that's part of why *so many* C-based systems have been hacked, cracked, and compromised over the last couple of decades.  *Simplifying* an explanation is okay, but not to the point where the explanation is *wrong*.  Arrays are not strings are not pointers.

Comment: @JohnBode Can you stop to blame me for the errors of the others ? I never say array are string. But Yes, I think that say strings are pointers is better to understand.

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that in c an array is itself a pointer to the first element of the array.

This is not correct - under most circumstances, an *expression*  of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", but an array object itself is not a pointer.  No storage is set aside for a pointer as part of an array object.

The *string literal* `"zero"` has type "5-element array of `char`", while both `"one"` and `"two"` have types "4-element array of `char`" (because strings are terminated with a zero-valued character, you need N+1 elements to store an N-character string).

Each string literal is an array expression, but since these expressions are not operands of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, and since they arent being used to initialize a character array, each expression is *converted* to a pointer expression, and the value of each expression is the address of the first element of the array.

> Therefore I would expect a memory address to be printed here and not an actual string. What am I misunderstanding here?

The `%s` conversion specifer tells `printf` to print the sequence of characters beginning at the specified address until it sees a string terminator - that's why you see `zero` as the output and not an address.  To print a pointer value, you'd use the `%p` conversion specifier like so:

```
printf( "%p\n", (void *) *words );
```

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of what you have done up to the printf is spot on - as you've written it, `*words` is in fact a pointer to a char. The `%s` format specifier is for printing strings, so it assumes that whatever pointer you pass it is actually an array of chars that ends with a `'\0'` char - the format c uses for storing strings. With that information, printf knows that it should just print all of the characters in the array until it finds that `'\0'` - which is exactly what it has done in this case. If you do want to print the address of that pointer, the correct format specifier is (as mentioned in Stargateur's answer) `%p`.

Answer (score 2):

As @Stargateur replied you need to both use the %p flag and use the (void *).
Please note that it will show you the starting address of the first string ('zero') and the next code will go over all the strings and print their address (think of the 3 strings as a 2D (two dimensions) strings array having different lengths.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 3

int main(void)
{
    char *words[LENGTH];
    words[0] = "zero";
    words[1] = "one";
    words[2] = "two";

    int len = 0;
    while(len<(int)LENGTH)
    {
        printf("%s\n", words[len]);
        printf("%p\n", (void *)words[len]);
        len++;
    }
    printf("\n%p\n", (void *)*words); // prints the first address only (the 'zero' address)

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`char *words[LENGTH];` defines an array of char*, i.e. char**. `*words` equals to `words[0]` which refers to "zero".

It is not safe to create such char* array. For example, the following code compiles OK, but its behavior is undefined.

```
char *words[1];
words[0] = "zero";
words[1] = "one";
words[2] = "two";
printf("%s\n", words[2]);
```

Comment: Its behavior is undefined. Whether it's unexpected depends on what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The context in which `*`(not `*` as in multiplication) matters,
when used in declearation as in `char *words[LENGTH]` word becomes array of pointers to char.

as far as pointers are concern `*` is **Value at address operator**, it gives Value stored at particular address, while `&` is **the address operator**, gives address of variable.

```
printf("%s\n",*words) // prints value at address to which word points
```

while

```
printf("%p\n",words) // prints address to which word points
```